# I am not able to serialize a user, I don't understand what happening

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

When I was try to login on my webpage I got that error, I was search that error on stackoverflow and on internet but I cannot solve that bug.
I have some questions about that?

1: when I was try to log **"user"** data. but instead of return **user obj** it will return **true**. Why?

2: In serializeUser **done** function why we give argument **user.id** instead of **user._id**. Because mongodb had **_id** field not that **id** field.

ERROR:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrjuQ.png)

This is what I got no my terminal.
[terminal img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbl0j.png)

Code snippet:

```
passport.use(new passportLocal({
  usernameField: 'email'
}, (email, password, done) => {
  console.log(email, password);
  usermodel.findOne({
    email: email
  }, (err, user_obj) => {
    console.log("user object get by database", user_obj)
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    if (!user_obj) {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: "There is no user with that ID."
      });
    } else if (user_obj) {
      console.log(user_obj._id)
      bcrypt.compare(password, user_obj.password, (err, varifiedUser) => {
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
        else if (varifiedUser) {
          return done(null, varifiedUser);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: "Incorrect password!"
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log("user object serialize", user);
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  usermodel.findById(user.id, (err, id) => {
    if (!err) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(err);
    }
  });
});


router.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/auth/quiz',
  failureRedirect: '/auth/login'
}));
```

And really sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter for `bcrypt.compare` returns a boolean that tells you if the passwords match and *not* the user data.

I would recommend rewriting it as an assignment on removing the optional callback.

```js
const match = bcrypt.compare(password, user_obj.password);
if (match) return done(null, user_obj);
```

This will pass the user object to the `serializeUser` callback.

serializeUser is used to add an identifier to the `req.session.passport` property so any unique value could be used. I believe you could just access user.id rather than _id with mongoose.